# How do I std::cout and std::cin at the same time?

Tags: c++, console-application

I am trying to create a console application that works as a messaging app running off of a server. I want to be able to recieve messages from a friend while I am typing my own message or while the console is awaiting my input (essentially I want to be able to cout while I cin). how would I do this? I'm assuming I will have to work on multiple threads but I cant find anything useful online.

Comment: Multiple threads are not needed. Just put your terminal in non-cannonical (raw) mode. You can then use a non-blocking read to process characters while you are typing. No matter how fast you type, you will still have time for millions of instructions between each character you type that can be used to read and display the characters received..

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will have to work with multiple threads. Essentially, one thread creates and sends messages, one thread receives them. So, they work in parallel and whenever a message is received it is simply printed (or written to a log or what have you) from the reader thread, and the writer thread will constantly be waiting for user input, and will allow the user to send a message. In this code, the message is printed as soon as its received. Also, this code is highly simplified since I have no idea how your message implementation is done, so all the message specifics are left out and a generic message is just printed at some interval. This kind of implementation will also result in messages received cutting off input. You would need some kind of input space separate from the output space so they don't intercept eachother visually like this, or you could use mutexes but this defeats the purpose of getting a message instantly.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

void reader()
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    std::cout << "This is a message...\n";
  }
}

void writer()
{
  std::string message;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    getline(std::cin, message);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  std::thread reader_thread(reader);
  std::thread writer_thread(writer);
  reader_thread.join();
  writer_thread.join();
  std::cout << "done!\n";

}
```

EDIT: Thought I would give more pointers on cin/cout intercepting each other. Basically, input and output happens in the same line and same place in most console implementations (Unless you use redirection or pipes or something). Most actual messaging apps have separate places for input and output. For example, you input your message somewhere, but the messages you receive show up above that. This kind of implementation means that input/output never stack on top of each other, but is also pretty much impossible to do with cin/cout. So, if you really want to do this kind of messaging application, you could use pipes or files OR you could use some libraries. Pretty much any GUI lib (Gtkmm, Qt) will let you do something like this, but if you are console-bound, ncurses will let you manipulate the console in complex ways like this so you can have one section for receiving messages and one for sending them.